# In sorbet, can you specify that a type is a descendent of a class?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I have a method that returns an object which could be one of many different types of object but which are all part of the same ancestor class. The precise object type is inferred dynamically.

However, I'm confused as to what to put for the return value in the signature. I've put a placeholder below using `instance_of` to illustrate the problem:

```
sig{params(instance_class: String).returns(instance_of ParentClass)}
def build_instance instance_class
  klass = Object.const_get(instance_class)
  return klass.new
end
```

Given that I don't know which precise class will be returned (and I'd prefer not to list them explicitly) but I *do* know that it will be a subclass of `ParentClass` is there a way in Sorbet to specify this? I could use `T.untyped` but it's unnecessarily loose.

Answer (score 3):

Through trial and error I've discovered that checking that the object *includes the type in its ancestors* is, if I understand correctly, sorbet's default behaviour.

Sorbet won't check that the object precisely matches the specified Type, only that it includes that type in its ancestors (perhaps this is what Typechecking in general means but I'm fairly new to the game).

To avoid the following error though:

`Returning value that does not conform to method result type https://srb.help/7005`

you also need to `T.cast()` the object that you return to the `ParentClass`:

```
sig{params(instance_class: String).returns(ParentClass)}
def build_instance instance_class
  klass = Object.const_get(instance_class)
  # NB instance is a descendent of ParentClass, not an instance...
  return T.cast(klass.new, ParentClass)
end
```

This seems to work but I'd love to know whether it's the correct way to solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, what you have is correct. `returns(ParentClass)` means returning an instance of ParentClass (read: "return a ParentClass"). An instance of a descendent of ParentClass is also an instance of ParentClass. You can check `klass.new.is_a?(ParentClass)` and it should return true. Sorbet raised the error 7005 because it doesn't know whether `klass` is a subclass of ParentClass, due to it being retrieved from `Object.const_get`.

Comment: @hdoan - that's super, thanks so much. And thanks for the great work with Sorbet itself - it's awesome to be able to use it. Are you guys planning to release any IDE plugins to help with autocompletion during development?

Comment: Thanks! I'm working on sorbet-rails only so I can't speak for the sorbet team, but I've heard that they are actively working on the IDE plugin (VSCode). Stay tuned!

Comment: Splendid news 

Comment: Oh and thanks for the sorbet-rails work too, I’d have been stuffed without it!